# Why is snapshot isolation lavel greater than serializable?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, isolation-level

Here what decompiler shows:

```
public enum IsolationLevel
{
  Unspecified = -1,
  Chaos = 16,
  ReadUncommitted = 256,
  ReadCommitted = 4096,
  RepeatableRead = 65536,
  Serializable = 1048576,
  Snapshot = 16777216,
}
```

But `Serializable` locks data thus providing more guarantees for concurrency correctness than `Snapshot` does. So what is the reason for value of Snapshot is greater?

Comment: Probably as it was implemented later.

Comment: Yes, it appeared later, but there is a place where snapshot could be put. Probably this is a breaking change...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerically greater has no particular bearing here on "level of isolation". Each item simply represents a different type of isolation. For what that *means* you must refer to the documentation. These are actually just bit-wise flags at 4-bit spacings. No particular meaning is intended by the values used, other than internal implementation details.

Comment: Hummm, I design ambient call cantext and I need to be sure that nested calls ask for isolation not greater than isolation of the parent context. So I thought I could just compare levels by value. It seems I cannot do it.

Comment: @voroninp indeed; you will have to write your own method to compare isolation